# Plugin works only when logged in (TypeError cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in)

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I have plugin on my website - Event Sceduler, and I dont know why but it doesnt work on mobile and some laptops. On my PC everything is OK.

The error is - TypeError cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in You are not allowed to do this.

at Object.succes  (escScheduler.js 270)

at ImportEvents  (escScheduler.js 260)

```
  $.ajax({
        url: esc_token.ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
            action: "getevents",
            security: esc_token.security,
            eventGroup: jsonFile
        },
        success: function (jsonEvents) {
            $.each(jsonEvents.data, function(i, item) {
                $.each(dates, function(j, item2) {
                    if (dates[j] == jsonEvents.data[i]['date']) {
                        if ((jsonEvents.data[i]['time'] !== null || jsonEvents.data[i]['time'].length > 0) && (jsonEvents.data[i]['title'] !== null || jsonEvents.data[i]['title'].length > 0)) {
                            events.push(jsonEvents.data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            var eventObject = new Object();
            eventObject.id = schedulerId;
            eventObject.events = events;
            escImportedEvents.push(eventObject);
        }
    });
```

Here is link to the file with error -  https://gist.github.com/DDushkin/c5a9f6a544dbdc13eb05a4b51bf6f11a
Maybe someone can help.

UPD: Here is the website http://www.rooftophub.com.ua/events

UPD2: I just noticed that plugin works only if I'm logged in

Comment: From the error message, it seems that the request failed due probably to an invalid security token (notice the `You are not allowed to do this` string?). However, it's hard to tell what's actually going on without seeing the site nor having more details about it (eg. do you have a caching plugin installed?)

Comment: @cabrerahector sorry) I updated post. added link to website and no there is no caching yet

Comment: I can see the JS error on my laptop. Try disabling all of your plugins (except for Event Scheduler) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: In case you want to know why you're seeing this error message, I took the liberty to open an issue at the plugin's Github repo: 
[TypeError cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in You are not allowed to do this](https://github.com/DDushkin/config/issues/1). Oddly enough, the owner of the repo deleted most of the plugin files a few minutes after I opened the issue, so...

Comment: @cabrerahector just tried to disable all plugins - no results

Comment: @cabrerahector  I just noticed that plugin works only if I'm logged in

Comment: Then the problem lies either in the plugin itself, or somehow your theme is what's causing the issue. Try switching to another theme for a moment and check again. If it's still broken after changing to another theme then it's the plugin.